# Show that $1^2+3^2+ \dots +(2n+1)^2=\frac{(n+1)(2n+1)(2n+3)}{3}$ using the identity $1^2+2^2+\dots + n^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$ without induction?

Tags: summation, induction

I've been trying to solve the following problem:

> Show that $1^2+3^2+ \dots +(2n+1)^2=\frac{(n+1)(2n+1)(2n+1)}{3}$ using the identity $1^2+2^2+\dots + n^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$.

I had the following idea, we write:

$$1^2+2^2+\dots + (2n+1)^2=\frac{(2n+1)((2n+1)+1)(2(2n+1)+1)}{6}=k$$

Let's pretend the identity we want to prove is true, then:

$$1^2+3^2+ \dots +(2n+1)^2=\frac{(n+1)(2n+1)(2n+1)}{3}=j$$

We take then $k-x=j$ and solve for $x$. If the given identities are true, $x$ must be the sum of $2^2+4^2+\dots+(2n)^2$, and we have that

$$x= \frac{2n (n+1) (2 n+1)}{3} $$

We still don't know that $x=2^2+4^2+\dots+(2n)^2$ but that can be easily proved by induction. I'd like to know: Is there some "neater" way that **doesn't** involve induction?

Despite the tag, I'd like to see an induction-free demonstration. I chose that tag because I couldn't think of anything better to choose.

Comment: Hint: $2^2  + 4^2  +  \cdots  + (2n)^2  = 4(1^2  + 2^2  +  \cdots  + n^2 )$

Comment: If you take $2^2$ out, you get $1^2 + 2^2 + ...+n^2$

Comment: Hint: Factor out $2^2$ from $x$ so that $x=4(1^2+2^2+\cdots+n^2)$.  Then, use the first result.

Comment: You don't need induction to know what $x$ is since $x=\sum_n (2n)^2=4\cdot\sum_n n^2$ and for this, you were given the formula.

Comment: @quantenstau Damn! I almost noticed that yesterday, I noticed that the sum of the first $n$ powers of even numbers is $4\sum_{i=0}^n (n-i)(n+1)$ but was unable to use this in a useful way.

Comment: The formula in the title is false: the last factor is $2n+\color{red}3$.

Comment: Maybe is more suitable to ask "how can one find this formula (but not just prove it) "instead of "Not involve induction". Actually, everything about integers involves induction.

Comment: The question is wrong. The final factor in the numerator isn't $(2n+1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: notice that $$\sum(2k)^2=\sum4k^2=4\sum k^2.$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $$S=1^1+3^2+\cdots+(2n-1)^2=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(2k-1)^2=\sum_{k=1}^{n}[4 k^2-4k+1]$$
$$S=4\sum_{k=1}^n k^2- 4\sum_{k=1}^{n} k+\sum_{k=1}^{n} 1$$
$$S=4\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}-4 \frac{n(n+1)}{2}+n=\frac{n(4n^2-1)}{3}$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the identity $$(2k+1)^2=4k^2+4k+1$$ which relates the sum of the odd squares to the sum of the squares.

The extra terms $4k+1$ are easily dealt with with a telescoping,

$$(k+1)^2-k^2=2k+1.$$

Altogether,

$$1^2+3^2+ \dots +(2n+1)^2=4\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6+2(n+1)^2-1-n.$$

Answer (score 1):

$ 1^2+2^2+\dots + n^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$ multiplying this by $ 2^2 $ gives the sum $ 2^2+4^2+\dots + (2n)^2 = \frac{2n(n+1)(2n+1)}{3} $ and subtracting this from the given identity results int the required equality.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo. Call the known sum $P_n$. The desired sum is$$\begin{align}P_{2n+1}-4P_n&=\frac{(2n+1)(2n+2)(4n+3)-4n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\\&=\frac{(n+1)(2n+1)}{3}(4n+3-2n)\\&=\frac{(n+1)(2n+1)(2n+3)}{3}.\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $S=1^2+3^2+5^2+\cdots+(2n+1)^2$$.

Next, consider the sums
$$S_1=2^2+4^2+6^2+\cdots+(2n)^2$$
$$S_2=1^2+2^2+3^2+\cdots+(2n+1)^2$$
Thus, we can calculate $S$ as $S=S_2-S_1$.

Let's evaluate $S_1$ and $S_2$ using the identity we are given.

Clearly,
$$S_2=\frac{1}{6}(2n+1)(2n+2)(4n+3)$$
and
$$S_1=2^2(1^2+2^2+\cdots+n^2)$$
$$S_1=2^2\cdot\frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1)$$

Therefore,
$$S=S_2-S_1$$
$$S=\frac{1}{6}\left[2(n+1)(2n+1)(4n+3)-4n(n+1)(2n+1)\right]$$
$$S=\frac{(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\left[8n+6-4n\right]$$
$$S=\frac{(n+1)(2n+1)(2n+3)}{3}$$
as desired.

Hope this helps :)